# What is meant by "Message sorting optimization records" in dovecot index?

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, e-mailrelay

Dovecot documentation here "https://doc.dovecot.org/developer_manual/design/indexes/index_file_format/#main-index" says that "Message sorting optimization records" are stored in the in the main index file. I am confused in what exactly is their content.

I read somewhere that they contain highest and lowest UIDs for a sorting criteria. But that didn't makes sense as shouldn't they be same for all criteria.

Comment: If we finally stopped reinventing the RDBMS wheel, none of those custom databases would make sense..

Answer (score 0):

Dovecot is a popular email server and its index files are responsible for managing and accessing email data. However, Message sorting optimization records don't appear to be a standard used term  with Dovecot.